# Not able to setup the SDK manager on eclipse indigo on windows 7

Tags: android

I went to Help>install new software. I was able to install the ADT plugins. But after configuring, the eclipse restarts. As soon as it starts i get a message "Could not find tools inside SDK "C:\Users\Nimit\android-sdks". When I try to open the open the Android SDK manager i get the message "Location of the Android SDK has not been setup in the preferences". When I go to preferences and select android, there's a message "Could not find the folder 'tools' in the "C:\Users\Nimit\android-sdks".

Can anybody help me?

Comment: are you sure your SDK path in prefrences is correct ?

Comment: see this steps--- read it carefully.. http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/

Comment: Try Downloading Android SDK again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason here is you don't have tool folder inside **"C:\Users\Nimit\android-sdks"**

check in windows explorer in which folder tools folder is present

in my case it is present in

**F:\android-sdk_r15-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools**

So in eclipse give path as

**F:\android-sdk_r15-windows\android-sdk-windows\**

Answer (score -1):

hope this link guides this problem. http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html
go to preference>android (out of those list) > go to browse and select the file which contains the sdk inside programing "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk".. now it will work ..